# Как задать скруглённый border c градиентом?

Tags: css

Как сделать вот такой градиентный border с отступом от кнопки  (отступ между кнопкой и border должен быть прозрачным)?

Идеально подходило бы свойство outline, но там нельзя задавать градиент для border.
border-image не походит, так как нужна скруглённость
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С двумя div элементами нельзя?

Comment: Можно и с двумя div попробовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

о, а это интересный квэст)

```css
body{background: black}
.b{
border-radius: 40px; font-size: 45px; color: white;
border: 15px double black;
/*говоришь надо прозрачный отступ от кнопки?
берём дабл и врубаем микшер дабы притянуть градиет сюда за уши =)
хотел конечно сделать фон с бордюром одного цвета и
микшером притянуть в них градиент из div'а обертки,
но в прозрачный промежуток попадает фон из него же =(
*/
mix-blend-mode: lighten;
}
#ok1{
background: linear-gradient(0deg, #9182b8 , #442B84);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, #9182b8 , #442B84);}
/*такой градиент катится лесом из-за кривых краёв, верно?*/

#ok2{
background: repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, #9182b8, #442B84, #442B84, #9182b8);
background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, #9182b8, #442B84, #442B84, #9182b8);
}

/*а знаешь что? есть еще такая идейка... */
#ok3{backgroung: rgba(77,77,77,1); mix-blend-mode: color-dodge;}
#f{
background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(100,50,150,0.1), rgba(150,140,230,0.1));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(100,50,150,0.1), rgba(150,140,230,0.1));
}
/*кривовато правда вышло, но все таки вполне честный
градиент =)*/
```

```html
<input type='button' value='кнопка 1' class='b' id='ok1'/>
<input type='button' value='кнопка 2' class='b' id='ok2'/>
<div id='f'>
<input type='button' value='кнопка 3' class='b' id='ok3'/>
</div>
```

Comment: Три нерабочих варианта. Или я что-то упустил?

Comment: на FF все работает, проверил бы и на остальных но свежих нету вообще, только старый хромиумный

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey, пофиксил, чекай =)

Comment: @puffleeck это лучшее решение, работает идеально, спасибо огромное!!! =)

Comment: @puffleeck Зачекал, в Chrome не работает. Даже если заставить в Chrome работать, я не могу себе представить, чтобы это работало с любым фоном. Сделайте фон белым, например.

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey, у меня и в огнелисе 202* года и в хромиуме 2011 года работает, а у вас нет... мб пора обновиться?))) ну правда, я хз, чем нужно это запускать чтоб оно не заработало. на счет любого фона, пффф... меняешь микшер с lighten на multiply и обратно при смене фона. позалипать на все варианты микшера(а их не мало) можно в песочнице там: https://webref.ru/css/mix-blend-mode

Comment: И это всё равно не решение проблемы. Бордеры черным цветом залиты в Chrome 104 (https://i.imgur.com/IdblfPh.png), в FF нормально, но вообще работает так себе на разных фонах (https://i.imgur.com/f4HEoRZ.png). Толку то от таких костылей?

Comment: @puffleeck нет ни одного универсального значения для mix-blend-mode. Тем более, фон необязательно будет монотонным. Залейте фон сложным градиентом от темных тонов к светлым и позалипайте с микшером. Мы не можем настроить микшер только для отдельных составляющих элемента. Подход интересный, но это не решение. Перспективным вариантом было бы использование маски, но, к сожалению, мне не удалось ее отрисовать с помощью CSS для данной задачи.

Answer (score 4):

В реальных проектах, я бы предпочёл вариант с SVG, как это, к примеру, предложил @VladimirGonchar (*за что ему плюсик*), но, как вариант, предложу еще такой способ:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #ccc, #ccc 10px, #fff 10px, #fff 20px);
}

.btn-gradient {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border-width: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #7b69a9 0%, #442b84 100%);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-gradient::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: -5px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #7b69a9, #442b84);
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
  -webkit-mask-composite: xor;
  mask-composite: exclude;
}
.btn-gradient:hover,
.btn-gradient:hover::before  {
  filter: brightness(1.2);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-gradient">Buy</button>
```

Comment: +1, глазам не верю, у меня как раз с масками не сложилось. Сел изучать.

Answer (score 2):

Правильный ответ: никак, CSS на данной стадии в такое не умеет.

Единственное, что Вы можете сделать сейчас – использовать SVG для кнопки (или обводки отдельно):

```css
body {
  background: #222;
}

.button {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 200px;
  height: 75px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover svg {
  filter: brightness(1.2);
}

.button svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="button">
  <svg width="263" height="72" viewBox="0 0 263 72" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect x="3" y="3" width="257" height="66" rx="33" fill="url(#paint0_linear_2_5)"/>
    <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="262" height="71" rx="35.5" stroke="url(#paint1_linear_2_5)"/>
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="paint0_linear_2_5" x1="3" y1="36" x2="260" y2="36" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop stop-color="#AD75D9"/>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#7319BA"/>
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="paint1_linear_2_5" x1="0" y1="36" x2="263" y2="36" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop stop-color="#AD75D9"/>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#7319BA"/>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
  </svg>
  <span>Заказать</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

нужные цвета, думаю, вы сами подобрать сможете.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 32px;
  height: 64px;
  width: 214px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, green, red);
}

.inner {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, green, red);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">
    More
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а если фон картинка? проще было наверное сразу один div - border(типа), второй - сплошной внутри первого

Comment: Почти идеально, только вот отступ между кнопкой и border должен быть прозрачным

Comment: делала до того, как вы отредактировали картинку в своем вопросе - там не было прозрачности.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.first {
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-radius: 30px;
        border-color: #725FA2;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        padding: 10px 3px 12px 3px;
}
.second {
    border:none;
    padding: 10px 50px 10px 50px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #9182b8 , #442B84);
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<span class="first">
    <button class="second">Buy</button>
</span>
```

P.S. Я не мастер по CSS.

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, у бордера нету градиента.

Comment: @OliverPatterson, Вы не ошибаетесь - там просто `border-color: #725FA2;` Товарищ даже не потрудился вникнуть в суть вопроса :))

Comment: @humster_spb До изменения вопроса не было ничего про border gradient

Comment: @YaMus, не лукавь - я сейчас посмотрел историю изменений вопроса, всё там сразу было